# Create Modular Jenkins Pipeline as a function

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins library that enables users to create a pipeline as a function. This works great because engineers can enter their parameters into a function called deployPipeline(param1 param2...) and run a pipeline. It will always run stage 1 stage 2 stage 3, in the same order. But I want to make this modular so engineers can call the function and insert the parameters to run specific stages of a pipeline in any order. For instance, some users might want to run an arbitrary script in the middle of the deploy pipeline. Or another group might have a requirement to run a stage more than once for a larger project.  Is there any way to do this in a declarative pipeline?